# Running a build on Jenkins Slave

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have done the following

1. Create a slave Node
2. In the Labels field added **Test**
3. Save the node configuration
4. Created a new Job
5. Selected the options Restrict where this project can run
6. In the Label expression field added **Test**
7. Save the job

When i build the job, i get the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\Test\src\test\java\test\data\Project Suites.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Not Sure whats wrong, The folder does not exist in the slave machine but exist in the Master machine.

But if i run it using the master it works fine.

Comment: did you set the Remot root directory for the slave machine?

Comment: Yes i did as C:\Jenkins\.

Comment: You might run into permission issues. You are trying to read Administrator files, maybe the jenkins user is not allowed to do that.

Comment: the jenkin user is the admin user and has ll the permission.

Comment: I have never faced such problems. but maybe the white space in the file name is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I dont understand the problem - you said it yourself, the file does not exist in the slave machine, and you're running jenkins on the slave. So of course its not going to find the file?

Just move the file to the slave machine and run the job on the slave?

Comment: The file exist in another location c:\jenkins in the slave machine